# Foreign key to values using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a webpage and site using Linq. The page contains a gridview which shows customers and bound by a List (Of Customer).

I use the below code to get a single customer

```
    Public Function GetCustById(ByVal id As Integer) As Customer Implements ICustomerService.GetCustById
        Return DataContext.Customers.SingleOrDefault(Function(c) c.Id = id)
    End Function
```

I then bind it to my gridview by passing all the customer IDs into the method. This displays all the rows as i need but i have one issue.

Some columns which are Foreign keys show up as 1,2 etc, Usually the way i have overcome this in the past ON DIFFERENT PROJECTS is by adding a sub query to my SQL query in the data layer but as you've guessed this is Linq so im not sure what is /not possible in order to get the Foreign Keys to display as values using Linq?

Im a little new to Linq so appreciate any help or articles that would help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Linq is capable of Joins, use them to connect two tables.

Comment: Erm.... get the Foreign Keys to display as values using Linq? So im wondering if there is a way to get the above code to include the value of a Foreign Key (as you could do when writing a sub query in a tableadapter)

Comment: Could you show us an SQL Example?

Comment: SELECT Name, Address, Age, GenderID From Customer WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID // This gets all the customer info with Gender being a FK. Here comes the sub query
(SELECT GenderValue From Genders Where Customer.GenderID = Genders.ID) As GenderValue

Comment: I assume you're talking LINQ-to-SQL here (as opposed to LINQ in general)? Do you have the [relationships mapped between tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb386950.aspx) giving you relationship properties in the generated code?

Comment: @TimRogers - Yes they are mapped. Sorry i wasnt aware there was a difference between saying Linq and Linq to SQL but yes its Linq To SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to separate the view from the entity classes (or domain classes if you like). So you will define a view model class, say `CustomerViewModel`, and project your `Customer` into it.

I'm not sure how you get a list of Customers (getting each single customer by Id is highly inefficient) but somewhere there will be an `IEnumerable<Customer>`. Let's call it `customers`. Now you can do

```
From c in customers_
Select New CustomerViewModel With { Name = c.Name, ... }
```

But now you can add properties to `CustomerViewModel` that are not in `Customer`! For instance

```
Select New CustomerViewModel
       With { Name = c.Name, TypeName = c.CustomerType.Name }
```

This `CustomerType` could be one of those foreign keys you want to show.

The result of the projection is an `IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel>` that you can show in the grid.